# JAVA Shopping Cart Design

Tags: java, object-oriented, e-commerce

Recently, I have appeared for coding exercise to design the Shopping Cart which should have following features:

1. handles barcoded (like Chips) and non-barcoded item (like Banana
   400gm)
2. Can add item, remove item, increment & decrement quantity of
   item.
3. Supports 2 For 1 offer for BarCoded Item.

I have completed the exercise and tried to follow the SOLID principle as much as I can. However, I can see there is lot of scope of improvement. I really appreciate if some one have a look at the code below and let me know the area of improvements.

1. **Booking.java**

   ```java
   package uk.co.supermarket;

   public class Basket {

       private List<CartItem> cartItemList = new ArrayList<>();

       private Float totalPriceBeforeDiscount = 0.0f;

       private Float totalPriceAfterDiscount = 0.0f;

       private Float totalDiscount = 0.0f;

       /* Key Value Pair of product code and Offer. */
       Map<String, Offer> offerMap = new HashMap<>();

       private DiscountStrategy discountStrategy;

       /**
        * @param offerMap
        * @param discountStrategy
        */
       public Basket(Map<String, Offer> offerMap, DiscountStrategy discountStrategy) {
           super();
           this.offerMap = offerMap;
           this.discountStrategy = discountStrategy;
       }

       public void addCartItem(CartItem cartItem) {
           int idxPos = cartItemList.indexOf(cartItem);
           if( idxPos != -1) {
               cartItem = cartItemList.get(idxPos);
               cartItem.addOne();
           }else {
               cartItemList.add(cartItem);
           }
           refreshTotal();
       }

       public int getTotalLineItem() {
           return cartItemList.size();
       }

       public Boolean removeCartItem(CartItem cartItem) {
           Boolean isLineItemRemoved = cartItemList.remove(cartItem);
           refreshTotal();
           return isLineItemRemoved;
       }

       /**
        * if cart item already in the basket then remove the item when there is only one quantity else reduce it by one.
        * if cart item not  
        **/
       public Boolean decreaseByOne(CartItem cartItem) {
           Boolean isLineItemReduced = false;
           int idxPos = cartItemList.indexOf(cartItem);
           if( idxPos != -1) {
               cartItem = cartItemList.get(idxPos);
               int qty = cartItem.reduceOne();
               if(qty == 0) {
                   cartItemList.remove(cartItem);
               }
               isLineItemReduced = true;
               refreshTotal(); 
           }
           return isLineItemReduced  ;
       }

       private void refreshTotal() {
           totalPriceBeforeDiscount = 0.0f;
           cartItemList.forEach(item -> totalPriceBeforeDiscount += item.getLineItemTotalBeforeDiscount());
           totalDiscount = discountStrategy.calculateDiscount(this.offerMap, this.cartItemList);
           totalPriceAfterDiscount = totalPriceBeforeDiscount - totalDiscount;
       }

       /**
        * @return the lineItemList
        */
       public List<CartItem> getCartItems() {
           return Collections.unmodifiableList(cartItemList);
       }

       /**
        * @return the totalPriceBeforeDiscount
        */
       public Float getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount() {
           return totalPriceBeforeDiscount;
       }

       public Float getTotalPriceAfterDiscount() {
           return totalPriceAfterDiscount;
       }

       public Float getTotalDiscount() {
           return totalDiscount;
       }

   }
   ```
2. **CartItem.java**

   ```java
   package uk.co.supermarket;
   public class CartItem {

       private final Product product;

       private Integer quantity;

       private Float weight ;


       /**
        * @param product
        */
       public CartItem(Product product, Integer quantity) {
           super();
           this.product = product;
           this.quantity = quantity;
       }

       /**
        * @param product
        */
       public CartItem(Product product) {
           this(product, 1); 
       }

       /**
        * @param product
        * @param weight
        */
       public CartItem(Product product, Float weight) {
           this(product); 
           this.weight = weight;
       }


       public Float getLineItemTotalBeforeDiscount() {
           switch(product.getProductType()) {
           case LOOSE : 
               return this.weight * product.getPrice().getUnitPrice();
           default :   
               return quantity * this.product.getPrice().getUnitPrice() ;
           }
       }


       /**
        * @return the product
        */
       public final Product getProduct() {
           return product;
       }


       /**
        * @return the quantity
        */
       public Integer addOne() {
           return quantity = quantity + 1;
       }

       /**
        * @return the quantity
        */
       public Integer reduceOne() {
           return quantity = quantity - 1;
       }

       /**
        * @return the quantity
        */
       public Integer getQuantity() {
           return quantity;
       }


       /* (non-Javadoc)
        * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
        */
       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           final int prime = 31;
           int result = 1;
           result = prime * result + ((product == null) ? 0 : product.hashCode());
           return result;
       }


       /* (non-Javadoc)
        * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
        */
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if (this == obj)
               return true;
           if (obj == null)
               return false;
           if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
               return false;
           CartItem other = (CartItem) obj;
           if (product == null) {
               if (other.product != null)
                   return false;
           } else if (!product.equals(other.product))
               return false;
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```
3. **Product.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket;

public class Product {

    private String productCode;

    private ProductType productType;

    private Price price;


    /**
     * @param productCode
     * @param productType
     * @param price
     */
    public Product(String productCode, ProductType productType, Price price) {
        super();
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public Price getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }


    /**
     * @return the productType
     */
    public ProductType getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((productCode == null) ? 0 : productCode.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((productType == null) ? 0 : productType.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (productCode == null) {
            if (other.productCode != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!productCode.equals(other.productCode))
            return false;
        if (productType != other.productType)
            return false;
        return true;
    }



}
```

4. **ProductType.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket;

public enum ProductType {

    BARCODED, LOOSE;
}
```

5. **Discount.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket.offers;

import uk.co.supermarket.CartItem;

public interface Discount {
    float applyDiscount(CartItem lineItem);
}
```

6. **DiscountType.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket.offers;

public enum DiscountType {

    TWO_FOR_ONE(new PercenatageDiscount(0.50f)),
    THREE_FOR_ONE(new PercenatageDiscount(0.33f));

    private final Discount discount;

    public Discount getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    private DiscountType(Discount discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

}
```

7. **Offer.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket.offers;

import uk.co.supermarket.Product;

public class Offer {

    private final Product product;
    private final DiscountType discountType;
    private final int quantity;

    /**
     * @param product
     * @param quantity
     * @param discountType
     */
    public Offer(Product product, int quantity, DiscountType discountType) {
        super();
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.discountType = discountType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the product
     */
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    /**
     * @return the quantity
     */
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    /**
     * @return the discount
     */
    public DiscountType getDiscountType() {
        return discountType;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Offer [product=" + product + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", discountType=" + discountType + "]";
    }



}
```

8. **PercenatageDiscount.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket.offers;

import uk.co.supermarket.CartItem;

public class PercenatageDiscount implements Discount{

    private float discountPercent ;

    public float getDiscountPercent() {
        return discountPercent;
    }

    public PercenatageDiscount(float discountPercent) {
        super();
        assert discountPercent <= 1;
        this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Discount [ discountPercent=" + discountPercent + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public float applyDiscount(CartItem lineItem) {
        return lineItem.getLineItemTotalBeforeDiscount() - (lineItem.getLineItemTotalBeforeDiscount() * ( discountPercent));
    }

}
```

9. **DiscountStrategy.java**

```java
package uk.co.supermarket;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import uk.co.supermarket.offers.Offer;

public class DiscountStrategy {

    public Float calculateDiscount(final Map<String, Offer> offerMap, final List<CartItem> set) {

        float totalDiscount = 0.0f;

        //apply discount if the offer matches with line item
        for(CartItem item : set) {
            Offer offer = offerMap.get(item.getProduct().getProductCode());
            if(offer != null 
                    && item.getProduct().getProductCode().equals(offer.getProduct().getProductCode())
                    && item.getQuantity() >= offer.getQuantity()) {
                        //This is the logic to handle the case when cart item quantity is more than offer 
                        // eg. when cart item are 3 and offer is 2 For 1 
                        int mod = item.getQuantity() % offer.getQuantity();
                        int quantityOnWhichOfferIsApplied = mod == 0 ? item.getQuantity() : item.getQuantity() - mod;
                        totalDiscount += offer.getDiscountType().getDiscount().applyDiscount(new CartItem(item.getProduct(), quantityOnWhichOfferIsApplied));
            }
        }
        return totalDiscount;
    }
}
```

10. **BasketTest.java**

````
package uk.co.supermarket;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import uk.co.supermarket.offers.DiscountType;
import uk.co.supermarket.offers.Offer;

public class BasketTest {

    private Basket basket = null;
    private DiscountStrategy discountStrategy = null;
    private Map<String,Offer> map = null;

    private Price price_5 =  new Price(5.0f);
    private Price price_10 =  new Price(10.0f);
    private Price price_15 =  new Price(15.0f);
    private Price price_20 =  new Price(20.0f);

    private Product bean_can = new Product("BEAN_CAN",ProductType.BARCODED,price_10);
    private Product coke_bottle = new Product("COKE_BOTTLE", ProductType.BARCODED,price_15);
    private Product coke_can = new Product("COKE_CAN", ProductType.BARCODED,price_5);
    private Product orange = new Product("ORANGE", ProductType.LOOSE,price_10);
    private Product apple = new Product("APPLE", ProductType.LOOSE,price_15);
    private Product banana = new Product("BANANA", ProductType.LOOSE,price_20);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        discountStrategy = new DiscountStrategy();
         map = new HashMap<>();
         basket = new Basket(map,discountStrategy);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddSingleBarCodedLineItem() {

        CartItem barCodedItem = new CartItem(bean_can);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem);

        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(10.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(10.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityOfSingleBarCodedProduct() {
        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);

        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(3 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(30.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(30.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityofSingleBarCodedProductWithRemovingOneUnit() {
        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(new Product("BEAN_CAN", ProductType.BARCODED,new Price(10.0f)));

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);

        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(40.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(40.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

        basket.decreaseByOne(barCodedItem_4);

        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(3 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(30.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(30.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityofSingleBarCodedProductWithRemovingCartItem() {

        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);

        //checking product with right quantity are added 
        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(40.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(40.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

        // remove the product altogether
        basket.removeCartItem(barCodedItem_4);

        assertTrue(0 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(basket.getCartItems().isEmpty());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityofMultipleBarCodedProduct() {

        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        CartItem barCodedItem_5 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);
        CartItem barCodedItem_6 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_5);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_6);

        //checking product with right quantity are added 
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityofMultipleBarCodedProductWithReducingOneUnitEach() {

        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        CartItem barCodedItem_5 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);
        CartItem barCodedItem_6 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_5);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_6);

        //checking product with right quantity are added 
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

        //reducing the quantity for both products
        basket.decreaseByOne(barCodedItem_4);
        basket.decreaseByOne(barCodedItem_5);

        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(3 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(1 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(45.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(45.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleQuantityofMultipleBarCodedProductWithRemovingOneCartItem() {

        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(bean_can);


        CartItem barCodedItem_5 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);
        CartItem barCodedItem_6 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_5);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_6);

        //checking product with right quantity are added 
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(70.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

        //reducing the quantity for both products
        basket.decreaseByOne(barCodedItem_4);

        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(3 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(60.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(60.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }

    @Test
    public void testAddSingleWeightedProduct() {
        CartItem weightedItem = new CartItem(orange, 0.20f);

        basket.addCartItem(weightedItem);

        assertTrue(1 ==  basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(2.0f ==  basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(2.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleWeightedProduct() {
        CartItem looseItem_1 = new CartItem(orange, 0.20f);
        CartItem looseItem_2 = new CartItem(apple, 0.40f);

        basket.addCartItem(looseItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(looseItem_2);

        assertTrue(2 ==  basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(1 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(1 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(8.0f ==  basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(8.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMultipleBarCodedAndMultipleWeightedLineItems() {
        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(coke_bottle);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(coke_can);
        CartItem weightedItem_1 = new CartItem(orange, 0.4f);
        CartItem weightedItem_2 = new CartItem(apple, 0.5f);
        CartItem weightedItem_3 = new CartItem(banana, 2.5f);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);

        basket.addCartItem(weightedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(weightedItem_2);
        basket.addCartItem(weightedItem_3);

        assertTrue(6 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(91.5f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(91.5f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());
    }

    @Test
    public void testApply2For1Offer() {
        map.put("COKE_CAN", new Offer(coke_can,2,DiscountType.TWO_FOR_ONE));
        map.put("BEAN_CAN", new Offer(bean_can,3,DiscountType.THREE_FOR_ONE));

        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(coke_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_2 = new CartItem(coke_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_3 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_4 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_5 = new CartItem(bean_can);
        CartItem barCodedItem_6 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_2);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_3);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_4);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_5);
        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_6);

        assertTrue(2 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(2 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(4 == basket.getCartItems().get(1).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(50.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(Math.abs(basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount() - 24.900002f) < 0.0001f);
        assertTrue(Math.abs(basket.getTotalDiscount()- 25.099998) < 0.0001f);

    }

    @Test
    public void testRemoveSingleBarCodedProduct() {
        CartItem barCodedItem_1 = new CartItem(bean_can);

        basket.addCartItem(barCodedItem_1);

        assertTrue(1 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(1 == basket.getCartItems().get(0).getQuantity());
        assertTrue(10.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(10.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

        basket.decreaseByOne(barCodedItem_1);

        assertTrue(0 == basket.getTotalLineItem());
        assertTrue(basket.getCartItems().isEmpty());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalPriceBeforeDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalPriceAfterDiscount());
        assertTrue(0.0f == basket.getTotalDiscount());

    }
}

```
````

Comment: Don't use float for prices since calculation results can become quite inaccurate. Better use BigDecimal. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496555/java-best-type-to-hold-price

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I should be using BigDecimal. I will make the correction. Is there anything from the design perspective I am missing here ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: The Basket class doesn't extend anything so there is no need for the super() call in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see how the system is architected is to look at the tests. It is great that you have provided such tests with the `BasketTest` class! So I will review your code by reviewing the `BasketTest`class.

- Initializing class fields to null is unnecessary and duplicate as they are automatically initialized to null (default value)
- `setup()` would be a better place to setup your products.
- Don't use field and variable names like `map`, `list`. They need to speak to whomever is reading the code. I have no idea what your `map` represents.
- Make name of the products like `"COKE_CAN"` constants and replace all occurrences in the code with the new constants.
- Without looking into the implementation, I cannot tell what the 2nd parameter means: `new Offer(coke_can, 2, DiscountType.TWO_FOR_ONE)`. I would like this code to be improved to be readable with less effort.
- Use  [assertArrayEquals(float[] expecteds, float[] actuals, float delta)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(float[],%20float[],%20float)) for comparing floats.
- Improve `testApply2For1Offer()` test. There you put elements to the `map` but it is not clear how the `map` interacts with the rest of the code.
- Every basked needs to have `DiscountStrategy` and offers in form of `Map<String, Offer>`. This does not seem right. I would think that there is only one `Discounts` object that can calculate a discount or final price for a given `Basket`. This is the biggest issues I see here, the design of the `Basket`.

Overall you did great with your design! I like it.

Comment: Thanks for your review. Excluding the last point, I have updated the code base for the review comment The last one require some thought before I do any change. I agree basket does not need to know about Offer. I think Offer should sit inside the product.